# Grab Strings with Python Attribute Access Link Access into Dictionary

Tags: python

I currently get output like this:

http://www.site.com/prof.php?pID=478http://www.site.com/prof.php?pID=693

after using suggestion from commenter below I have:

```
urls = [el.url for el in domainLinkOutput]
return HttpResponse(urls)
```

How do I turn this output into a python dictionary like:

```
urls = { '0': 'http://www.site.com/prof.php?pID=478', '1': 'http://www.site.com/prof.php?pID=693' }
```

Comment: What do you plan to use `pID` / `id` for ?

Comment: These are merely urls from BING

Comment: Are you trying to use regex to access attributes of a `namedtuple`?

Comment: I'm trying to literally parse out the value of url attribute from the outputted information

Comment: And I'm saying that the output looks like the `repr` form of some `namedtuples` that you've concatenated together.  I question whether you're using whatever API that generated these strings properly.

Comment: Regex seems like the wrong tool here

Comment: What is generating this output?

Comment: This output is coming from mechanize

Comment: So, you've mentioned using mechanize... now looking at it, are you also using Django and trying to return a json object of these urls? Please tell us what you're trying to achieve as what you're asking how to do is clearly not where your problem lies... it'll be much simpler than us picking our way through several revisions of your post to work out what your actual problem is ;)

Comment: Haha, I'm just trying to grab the url's from the output, which I'm doing now - thanks to you. I am now trying to put them into a python dictionary, so then I can quick insert them into a local mysql db

Comment: @CodeTalk why are you doing `return HttpResponse` - why aren't you just returning the list? Why specifically do you want a `dict` if you just wish to insert those urls into a database?

Comment: Well, that's a whole different question now, which isn't very nice to those who already answered and will confuse anyone visiting this page. Once you have the urls in a list, as Jon Clemens suggested in the previous comment, `dict(zip(range(len(urls)), urls))` will do it.

Comment: @JonClements - what would be the proper data structure to then just import into a db ?

Comment: @PauloAlmeida that's a long way of writing `dict(enumerate(urls, 1))` :)

Comment: @JonClements - can you please update your answer to show this ?

Comment: @CodeTalk well, I'm guessing the key element you're trying to create is an autoincrementing/unique key the database should be assigning anyway... so if your table is set up correctly, you should just need to insert the url column... But we're going massively off scope now..

Comment: @JonClements, Indeed :) I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: So what are my options now is a dictionary the best data structure to use or a list? to then insert into db

Comment: @CodeTalk You can use either... I'd go for a list, but first I'd read up on a basic Python/MySqlDb tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you need regex here - just use attribute access on the `Link` objects you have...

If you have a list of `Link` objects, then use something like:

```
urls = [el.url for el in list_of_objects]
```

You should just be able to get the url by `Link_object.url`...

Comment: Thanks, but I dont need the parameters and just the value of url

Comment: @Rejected okay thanks - updated question to suggest he just needs attribute on the `Link` objects instead

Comment: @JonClements I'm not sure if those are actually objects, or is that's one big long string that he's got as "output".

Comment: I'm getting output like  : 
http://www.thesite.com/prof.php?pID=478http://www.thesite.com/prof.php?pID=693 . Is there an easy way to put these into a python dictionary ?

Comment: How can I get into a python dictionary, this kind of output above ^

Comment: @CodeTalk update your question with the code you're using to get the output above, and the exact output you're getting....

Comment: Updated Jon !  Check it out

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex for matching the urls:

```
url='([^']+)'
```

Sample output:

```
    [0] => http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=478
    [1] => http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=527
    [2] => http://www.somesite.com/prof.php?pID=645
```

If you want to exclude the parameters, use

```
url='([^'?]+)
```

Sample output:

```
    [0] => http://www.somesite.com/prof.php
    [1] => http://www.somesite.com/prof.php
    [2] => http://www.somesite.com/prof.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `re.finditer`.

```
r = re.compile("url='(.*?)'")
for match in r.finditer(input):
    print match.group[1]
```

You can read the Python documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer).